# Have the three goalkeepers of a squad ever been used during a World Cup?

Tags: football, history, world-cup, goalkeeper

Usually, the same goalkeeper plays all the games during the competition, and I rarely saw the second goalkeeper playing, even less the third one.

Have there been occurrences of teams having their three goalkeepers having played during the competition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four teams (France, Belgium, Czechoslovakia and Greece)  used their three goalkeepers:

> In all, only four teams have ever used three goalkeepers in a single
> World Cup tournament. That's out of 371 teams to have qualified for
> the finals – surely time for Fifa to change the rules.
>
> First to use a trio of keepers were France in 1978. The No1 was
> Jean-Paul Bertrand-Demanes who played in Les Bleus' opening game
> against Italy. In the second group game against Argentina,
> Bertrand-Demanes smashed either his back or head (it varies between
> reports) on a post after pulling off a save and had to be replaced by
> Dominique Baratelli, a 31-year-old who had made sporadic appearances
> since 1969. He conceded the winning goal against Argentina and was
> replaced for France's final group game by Dominique Dropsy. The game
> against Hungary was Dropsy's debut and he would go on to win another
> 16 caps. Neither Baratelli nor Bertrand-Demanes would ever play for
> the national side again.
>
> Belgium went into the 1982 tournament with the eccentric (he served a
> three-month ban in 1980 after elbowing a linesman in a Belgian Cup
> match) but hugely talented Jean-Marie Pfaff as their first choice.
> Pfaff had been welcomed, somewhat apprehensively, back to the fold
> after missing the 1978 European Championships because of his practical
> joking, but he couldn't keep his inner comedian under wraps. He was
> dropped following the first group stage after apparently pretending to
> drown in the swimming pool at the team hotel. His replacement in
> Belgium's opening game in the second group stage was Theo Custers,
> whose performance against Poland was so abject it was his last
> ("Custers's last stand," notes the World Cup historian Cris Freddi).
> For the Belgian's final game Jacky Munaron took the gloves.
>
> Also in 1982, Czechoslovakia used three keepers. Zdenek Hruska played
> from start to finish against Kuwait, but Stanislav Seman was preferred
> for the Czech's game against England. A calamitous performance – it
> would be his last for the national side – lasted 75 minutes before he
> broke a finger and was replaced by third-choice Karel Stromsik, who
> kept the No1 spot for the final group game.
>
> The most recent team to use three goalkeepers in a single tournament
> were the hapless Greece side of 1994. The Greeks had gone undefeated
> through qualifying and named the experienced Antonis Minou, who had
> conceded only twice in five qualifiers, as No1 for the opening game
> against Argentina. A 4-0 defeat saw 25-year-old AEK keeper Elias
> Atmatsidis in goal against Bulgaria. Another 4-0 defeat followed and
> he was replaced by 24-year-old Christos Karkamanis for the final group
> game. That brought a slight improvement in fortunes – a 2-0 defeat to
> Nigeria.

Source: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2010/may/26/world-cup-2010-three-goalkeepers) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190323204338/https://www.theguardian.com/football/2010/may/26/world-cup-2010-three-goalkeepers)).

Answer (score 3):

There already is an answer which provides several occurrences of this happening. (And which probably is complete until the source of that answer was published, which is shortly before [2010 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup).)

Let us collect collaboratively in this community wiki answer other occurrences that we are able to find.

- At [2018 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup), Saudi Arabia used all three goalkeepers in the [group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A): [Abdullah Al-Mayouf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_Al-Mayouf), [Mohammed Al-Owais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_Al-Owais) and [Yasser Al-Mosailem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasser_Al-Mosailem).
- At 2018 FIFA World Cup, all three Tunisian goalkeepers [Mouez Hassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouez_Hassen), [Farouk Ben Mustapha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farouk_Ben_Mustapha) and [Aymen Mathlouthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aymen_Mathlouthi) played in the [group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_G).
- At [2015 FIFA Women's World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_FIFA_Women%27s_World_Cup), all
  three Japan goalkeepers [Erina Yamane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erina_Yamane), [Ayumi Kaihori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayumi_Kaihori) and [Miho Fukumoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miho_Fukumoto) played in the [group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_FIFA_Women%27s_World_Cup_Group_C).
  Kaihori played in all matches in the [knockout stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_FIFA_Women%27s_World_Cup_knockout_stage).